# Bottom Navigation view With Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

I Am Using Bottom Navigation View With Navigation Drawer.
I have Same Item At Navigation Drawer And Bottom navigation view.
 Now, My Problem is when I select The Item from Navigation Drawer The Bottom Navigation Item Is not Changed It still Highlighted First Item. How to Solve it Please Help.

Comment: Why would you have two separate UI elements that do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the item from Navigation Drawer, you should call `mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_navigation_item);`
don't use any same code in selecting drawer items and bottom navigation items.
just add codes to `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, because when you call `mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_navigation_item);` everywhere, this will run the codes inside `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Thank  For Help I was Solved It.